# I need redirect 301 search results

Tags: redirect

I need to redirect from:

```
/?s=search&post_type=library to /library/?s=search&post_type=library
```

I'm using:

```
RewriteRule ^s=(.*)%&post_type%=library$ https://www.cyberdocentes.com/library/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Also:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^s=(.*)%&post_type=library$ 
RewriteRule ^$ https://www.cyberdocentes.com/library/$1 [R=301,L]
```

And:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/(.*)%&post_type%=library$ https://www.cyberdocentes.com/library/$1
```

Thank you for you help.

Comment: I do not do full directory redirection, because I'm using two types of search.

The results of the main form were redirected to the blog directory, but in doing so, the results of the post_type are also being redirected to the blog directory, so I want to separate them and show them in the library directory.

Answer (score 0):

I already solved the redirect, I am using:

To redirect the results of post_type to the "library" page:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^s=(.*)&post_type=library$
RewriteRule ^$ https://www.cyberdocentes.com/library/$1 [R=301,L]
```

And to redirect the search results of articles to the "blog" page:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^s=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^$ https://www.cyberdocentes.com/blog/?s=%1 [L=301,R]
```

If you have a better solution, I hope you help me, thank you very much.